# В чем разница между NetFramework и NetCore

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

При попытке подключить библиотеку к uwp приложению получил вот такое предупреждение:
"Проект предназначен для ".NetCore", в то время как ссылка файла предназначена для ".NetFramework""
[image: 1]
Вроде, и то платформа, и то платформа, так в чем разница, зачем их две и возможна ли связь между ними (подключать одно к другому и наоборот)?

Comment: `NetCore` - это кросс-платформенная реализация `.NetFramework`. На данный момент они довольно сильно отличаются, в NetCore еще много чего не реализовано по сравнению с NetFramework, поэтому библиотеки написанные для NetFramework нельзя использовать для NetCore. Нужно либо попытаться перекомпилировать ее для NetCore если есть исходники. Либо попытаться найти существующий аналог для NetCore, но аналог может в приципе и отсутствовать

Comment: и еще вот: [What's the difference between .NET Core, .NET Framework, and Xamarin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063837/whats-the-difference-between-net-core-net-framework-and-xamarin)

Comment: @Grundy почему не пишете это всё в виде ответа?

Comment: @Anatol, Павел уже дал хороший ответ :)

Comment: @Grundy ну Вы раньше написали и тоже неплохо. Это был не вопрос, а побуждение)

Comment: @Anatol, не, честно говоря, не особо тянет на ответ, поэтому не стал добавлять

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/312026/

Comment: тут ещё могу добавить, что при создании бибилиотек лучше выбирать NET Standard чтобы в дальнейшем её можно было подключить и к NET Core, и к NET Framework  (вроде ещё поддерживается ASP.NET и Xamarin)

Answer (score 26):

.NET Framework - это старая платформа, работающая только под Windows.

.NET Core - это новая платформа, которая может работать как под Windows, так и под Linux. Но она еще довольно "сырая" - множество инструментов еще не перенесены на нее.

Подключить одно к другому не получится, потому что у них разные системные библиотеки (а также разные системы сборки если вы используете Visual Studio версии 2015 или ниже).

---

Кроме них, есть еще платформы:

Mono - может работать как под Windows, так и под Linux. Пытается быть совместимой с .NET Framework.

UWP - платформа для написания Windows-приложений, использующих WinRT. Не знаю про совместимость с .NET Framework.

Silverlight - старая платформа (застряла примерно на уровне .NET 4.5), предназначенная для работы в браузере (вроде java-апплетов). Не так давно была серьезно ранена гуглом, который перестал поддерживать NPAPI в своем Хроме. Не совместима с .NET Framework.

.NET Compart Framework -  несовместимая вариация .NET Framework для Windows CE. Сейчас находится на той же свалке, куда был выброшен Windows CE.

Unity - форк Mono, платформа для написания графических (в том числе 3D) приложений. Есть вариант встраивания в браузер (<s>не работает в Хроме из-за отказа от NPAPI</s> в Хроме работает благодаря технологии Web Assembly).

PCL (Portable Class Library) - общее подмножество разных версий .NET Framework, UWP и Silverlight. Совместима с ними в одну сторону (PCL-библиотеку можно использовать на перечисленных платформах).

.NET Standard - новая реинкарнация PCL. От PCL отличается подходом к версионированию: если для PCL разработчик библиотеки выбирает список поддерживаемых платформ, то для .NET Standard выбирается версия стандарта (а для платформ известно какие версии ими поддерживаются).

Comment: Добавлю еще [статью про .NET Standard](https://habrahabr.ru/post/314588/) и ссылку на репозиторий, где [кодом объясняется](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/8939f305567e1755412d6dc0b8baf1b7), как этот стандарт относится к перечисленным платформам.

Comment: у Core под Mac тоже есть реализация

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

Answer (score 2):

Если посмотреть какие версии NetStandard поддерживает UWP https://habrahabr.ru/post/312026/

То увидим, что это 1.4. Текущая максимальная версия 1.6

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/mt590967.aspx

> Наконец, .NET Core — это нижележащая инфраструктура, от которой
> зависит .NET Native. Когда проектировали .NET Native, стало понятно,
> что .NET Framework не подойдет в качестве фундамента для библиотек
> классов этой инфраструктуры. Дело в том, что .NET Native статически
> связывает инфраструктуру с приложением, а затем удаляет все лишнее,
> что не нужно приложению. (Здесь я сильно упрощаю общую картину, но
> идею вы уловили. Подробнее на эту тему см. «Inside .NET Native» по
> ссылке [bit.ly/1UR7ChW](http://bit.ly/1UR7ChW).)
>
> Традиционная реализация .NET Framework не
> предусматривает разбиения на модули, поэтому компоновщик (linker) не
> может включить в приложение лишь ту часть инфраструктуры, которая
> нужна приложению. Но .NET Core, по сути, является ответвлением .NET
> Framework, реализация которой оптимизирована с учетом модульности.
> Другое преимущество этой реализации — возможность поставлять .NET Core
> Framework как набор NuGet-пакетов, что позволяет вам обновлять
> индивидуальные классы вне самой .NET Framework. Однако, прежде чем
> двигаться дальше, давайте обсудим изменения в NuGet.

ПО UWP ориентировано на .Net Core, поэтому не совместимо с библиотеками  .NET Framework

Comment: как поддержка UWP версий NetStandard относится к вопросу _В чем разница между NetFramework и NetCore?_

Comment: Тем, что UWP  основано на .Net Core, но максимальная версия .NetStandard 1.4

Comment: UWP не может быть основано на Core, потому что появилось раньше

Comment: А когда появилось .Net Native?  Там все завязано на .NetStandard, а в UWP был аналог .Net Core